# ParseUser saveInBackground still not saving after Facebook Login

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform

I have login into facebook, and use ParseFacebookUtil to login Parse. I can get Current User, and put my "highscore" into it. However, when I perform saveInBackground, it error statusbg "Cannot save a ParseUser until it has been signed up".

```
    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("highscore", getHighScore());
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
              public void done(ParseException e) {
                     if (e == null) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "SAVE SUCCESSFUL");   

                     } else {
                         Log.d(TAG, "SAVE FAILED " + e.getCause());   
                     }
                   }
                 });

    }
```

My code for ParseFacebookUtil login as below

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(fbUser.getId(), session.getAccessToken(), 
    session.getExpirationDate(), new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException err) {                   
        if (parseUser != null) {
            // The user has been saved to Parse.
            if (parseUser.isNew()) {
                // This user was created during this session with Facebook Login.                       
                Log.d(TAG, "ParseUser created.");

                // Call saveInventory() which will save data to Parse if connected. 
                CarRunnerApplication app = ((CarRunnerApplication)getApplication());
                app.saveInventory();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "User exists in Parse. Pull their values: " + parseUser);

                // This user existed before. Call loadInventory() which has logic
                // to check Parse if connected.
                CarRunnerApplication app = ((CarRunnerApplication)getApplication());
                app.loadInventory();
            }

            loadInventoryFragment();
        } else {
            // The user wasn't saved. Check the exception.
            Log.d(TAG, "User was not saved to Parse: " + err.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

It used to worked, and I don't know since when it's no longer working. Can someone shed some light how to even debug it... Thanks.

Comment: Have you stepped through in a debugger to see what it's doing?

Comment: I can debug, but I can't debug into saveInBackground function of the Parse library, as it's a jar file.